# interpretation of $d(n) \leq \exp\Big(O\Big(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\Big)\Big)$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, asymptotics

I know that $d(n) \leq \exp\Big(O\Big(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\Big)\Big)$where $d(n)$ denotes the number of divisor of $n$, e.g. $d(6)=4$. I'm struggling to interpret what this bounds means. In particular the ratio of the logarithms.

Clearly $\log \log n$ is much smaller than $\log n$ for sufficiently large $n$

so the ratio gets bigger as n gets larger but I am not sure I really understand what this bound is telling me properly. I understand its saying the number of divisors of $n$ is bounded but that doesn't feel like a very deep understanding of the bound.

Comment: Do you know what the $O$ means?

Comment: @jjagmath yes, although still fairly new to it. $f(x)=O(g(x)$ means $|f(x)| \leq Mg(x)$ for all $x \geq x_{0}$. so $d(n) \leq \exp\Big(M \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\Big)$  (I omitted the absolute value on $d(n)$ since its always positive).

Comment: Letting $n\approx 2^m$ then $\log\log n=\log \log 2+\log m.$ So: $$\log d(n)=O\left(\frac{m}{\log m}\right)$$

Comment: So if $n$ has $m$ bits in binary, then $\log d(n)$ is bounded above by some constant multiple of $m/\log(m).$

Comment: So it means there exists a positive constant $M$ such that $d(n) \leq \exp\Big(M \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\Big)$. What more do you need to read from that? You may write it in equivalent forms, like $\log d(n) \leq M \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$ or $d(n) \leq n^{M/\log\log n}$, but that's it.

Comment: @jjagmath I guess I was just getting confused by the denominator being two logarithms.

Comment: Alternatively you can require this as: $$d(n)= n^{O\left(\frac1{\log\log n}\right)}$$

Comment: With equality at $n = 6983776800 = 2^5 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19$ and $d(n) = 2304,$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1.5379398606751... \right)} =  n^{ \left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right) }. $$ Full details of the proof appear in J.-L. Nicolas et G. Robin. *Majorations explicites pour le nombre de diviseurs de n*, Canad. Math. Bull., 26, 1983, 485--492.

Comment: With equality at a number $n$ near $6.929 \cdot 10^{40},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)}.   $$ Compare this one with Theorem 317 in Hardy and Wright, attributed to Wigert (1907),
$$ \limsup \frac{\log d(n)  \log \log n}{\log n} = \log 2.  $$